# Google maps: Customize only the destination marker in a route without setting supressmarkers as true

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new here and this is my first question.
I am currently working on the google maps api v3. 
What am trying to do is that, in a route with a number of waypoints i need to customize the destination marker only,while keeping all the other markers in the route as it is,like default 'A','B' etc. I would have given an image here but i don't have the reputation required to do that.

Anyway I wanted to know is there any way of doing this.
Thanks.

[I have tried using the supressmarkers:true property of directionsrenderer object but that would hide all the markers which is not I wanted.]

Answer (score 0):

The only way to modify the markers individually is to use the [suppressMarkers: true](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) option, then render them all yourself.  If they are rendered by the DirectionsRenderer you can't access or modify them.  You can make markers (or find markers from Google) that are lettered like the ones rendered by the DirectionsRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

I just came through a thread on google discussion groups that actually can alter the default markers rendered by DirectionsRenderer. A solution presented by **ICP-Fan** [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/rQQ_6jnwii8/2O-zMzoZadkJ). It's somehow tricky but it works